# Some extensions of MediaWiki does not work

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I have installed MediaWiki CMS from Debian.
Before update OS from Squeeze to Jessie, all extensions worked fine.
After the upgrade, some of the extensions stopped working: Gadgets, WikiEditor. The "Gadgets" extension is in the list of extensions used on the version page. The Gadgets configuration page is in the list of seperate pages, as well as in the user settings in full. But on the pages with wiki articles, gadgets do not appear (for example Gadget-UTCLiveClock). I do not see the call to this script in the source code of the page.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ke7b0.png)

```
<script>(window.RLQ=window.RLQ||[]).push(function(){mw.config.set({"wgCanonicalNamespace":"","wgCanonicalSpecialPageName":false,"wgNamespaceNumber":0,"wgPageName":"Заглавная_страница","wgTitle":"Заглавная страница","wgCurRevisionId":774,"wgRevisionId":774,"wgArticleId":1,"wgIsArticle":true,"wgIsRedirect":false,"wgAction":"view","wgUserName":"Ярослав","wgUserGroups":["bureaucrat","svnadmins","sysop","*","user","autoconfirmed"],"wgCategories":[],"wgBreakFrames":false,"wgPageContentLanguage":"ru","wgPageContentModel":"wikitext","wgSeparatorTransformTable":[",\t."," \t,"],"wgDigitTransformTable":["",""],"wgDefaultDateFormat":"dmy","wgMonthNames":["","январь","февраль","март","апрель","май","июнь","июль","август","сентябрь","октябрь","ноябрь","декабрь"],"wgMonthNamesShort":["","янв","фев","мар","апр","май","июн","июл","авг","сен","окт","ноя","дек"],"wgRelevantPageName":"Заглавная_страница","wgRelevantArticleId":1,"wgRequestId":"dfc9594aa741e7ad292fdee8","wgUserId":2,"wgUserEditCount":1249,"wgUserRegistration":1347855570000,"wgUserNewMsgRevisionId":null,"wgIsProbablyEditable":true,"wgRestrictionEdit":["sysop"],"wgRestrictionMove":["sysop"],"wgIsMainPage":true,"wgWikiEditorEnabledModules":{"toolbar":true,"dialogs":true,"preview":false,"publish":false},"wgCategoryTreePageCategoryOptions":"{\"mode\":0,\"hideprefix\":20,\"showcount\":true,\"namespaces\":false}"});mw.loader.state({"site.styles":"ready","noscript":"ready","user.styles":"ready","user.cssprefs":"ready","user":"ready","user.options":"loading","user.tokens":"loading","mediawiki.legacy.shared":"ready","mediawiki.legacy.commonPrint":"ready","mediawiki.sectionAnchor":"ready","mediawiki.skinning.interface":"ready","skins.vector.styles":"ready"});mw.loader.implement("user.options@0edrpvk",function($,jQuery,require,module){mw.user.options.set({"gender":"male","timecorrection":"ZoneInfo|420|Asia/Barnaul","gadget-DotsSyntaxHighlighter":"1","gadget-HotCat":"1","gadget-UTCLiveClock":"1","gadget-Wikilinker":"1","gadget-addThisArticles":"1","gadget-popups":"1","gadget-preview":"1","usebetatoolbar":"1","usebetatoolbar-cgd":"1","watchlisttoken":"SOME_TOKEN_1"});});mw.loader.implement("user.tokens@USER_TOKENS",function ( $, jQuery, require, module ) {mw.user.tokens.set({"editToken":"SOME_TOKEN_2","patrolToken":"SOME_TOKEN_3","watchToken":"SOME_TOKEN_4","csrfToken":"SOME_TOKEN_5"});/*@nomin*/;});mw.loader.load(["mediawiki.page.startup","skins.vector.js"]);});</script>

<script>(window.RLQ=window.RLQ||[]).push(function(){mw.loader.load(["mediawiki.action.view.postEdit","site","mediawiki.user","mediawiki.hidpi","mediawiki.page.ready","mediawiki.searchSuggest","mediawiki.page.watch.ajax","ext.gadget.referenceTooltips","ext.gadget.directLinkToCommons","ext.gadget.preview","ext.gadget.popups","ext.gadget.addThisArticles","ext.gadget.HotCat","ext.gadget.Wikilinker","ext.gadget.DotsSyntaxHighlighter","ext.gadget.UTCLiveClock"]);});</script><script>(window.RLQ=window.RLQ||[]).push(function(){mw.config.set({"wgBackendResponseTime":385});});</script>
```

In mirror version (Debian Squeee, MediaWiki 1.25) all work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nq0eC.png)

```
<script>if(window.mw {mw.config.set({"wgCanonicalNamespace":"","wgCanonicalSpecialPageName":false,"wgNamespaceNumber":0,"wgPageName":"Заглавная_страница","wgTitle":"Заглавная страница","wgCurRevisionId":774,"wgRevisionId":774,"wgArticleId":1,"wgIsArticle":true,"wgIsRedirect":false,"wgAction":"view","wgUserName":"Ярослав","wgUserGroups":["bureaucrat","svnadmins","sysop","*","user","autoconfirmed"],"wgCategories":[],"wgBreakFrames":false,"wgPageContentLanguage":"ru","wgPageContentModel":"wikitext","wgSeparatorTransformTable":[",\t."," \t,"],"wgDigitTransformTable":["",""],"wgDefaultDateFormat":"dmy","wgMonthNames":["","январь","февраль","март","апрель","май","июнь","июль","август","сентябрь","октябрь","ноябрь","декабрь"],"wgMonthNamesShort":["","янв","фев","мар","апр","май","июн","июл","авг","сен","окт","ноя","дек"],"wgRelevantPageName":"Заглавная_страница","wgUserId":2,"wgUserEditCount":885,"wgUserRegistration":1347855570000,"wgUserNewMsgRevisionId":null,"wgIsProbablyEditable":true,"wgRestrictionEdit":["sysop"],"wgRestrictionMove":["sysop"],"wgIsMainPage":true,"wgWikiEditorEnabledModules":{"toolbar":true,"dialogs":true,"hidesig":true,"preview":false,"previewDialog":false,"publish":false},"wgCategoryTreePageCategoryOptions":"{\"mode\":0,\"hideprefix\":20,\"showcount\":true,\"namespaces\":false}"});}</script><script>if(window.mw){mw.loader.implement("user.options",function($,jQuery){mw.user.options.set({"ccmeonemails":0,"cols":80,"date":"default","diffonly":0,"disablemail":0,"editfont":"default","editondblclick":0,"editsectiononrightclick":0,"enotifminoredits":0,"enotifrevealaddr":0,"enotifusertalkpages":1,"enotifwatchlistpages":1,"extendwatchlist":0,"fancysig":0,"forceeditsummary":0,"gender":"unknown","hideminor":0,"hidepatrolled":0,"imagesize":2,"math":0,"minordefault":0,"newpageshidepatrolled":0,"nickname":"","norollbackdiff":0,"numberheadings":0,"previewonfirst":0,"previewontop":1,"rcdays":7,"rclimit":50,"rows":25,"showhiddencats":0,"shownumberswatching":1,"showtoolbar":1,"skin":"vector","stubthreshold":0,"thumbsize":5,"underline":2,"uselivepreview":0,"usenewrc":0,"watchcreations":1,"watchdefault":1,"watchdeletion":0,"watchlistdays":3,"watchlisthideanons":0,"watchlisthidebots":0,"watchlisthideliu":0,"watchlisthideminor":0,"watchlisthideown":0,"watchlisthidepatrolled":0,"watchmoves":0,"watchrollback":0,"wllimit":250,"useeditwarning":1,"prefershttps":1,"mathJax":false,"language":"ru","variant-gan":"gan","variant-iu":"iu","variant-kk":"kk","variant-ku":"ku","variant-shi":"shi","variant-sr":"sr","variant-tg":"tg","variant-uz":"uz","variant-zh":"zh","searchNs0":true,"searchNs1":false,"searchNs2":false,"searchNs3":false,"searchNs4":false,"searchNs5":false,"searchNs6":false,"searchNs7":false,"searchNs8":false,"searchNs9":false,"searchNs10":false,"searchNs11":false,"searchNs12":false,"searchNs13":false,"searchNs14":false,"searchNs15":false,"gadget-referenceTooltips":1,"gadget-HotCat":"1","gadget-UTCLiveClock":"1","gadget-addThisArticles":"1","gadget-popups":"1","gadget-preview":"1","timecorrection":"ZoneInfo|360|Asia/Novosibirsk","usebetatoolbar":"1","usebetatoolbar-cgd":"1","watchlisttoken":"SOME_TOKEN_1"});},{},{});mw.loader.implement("user.tokens",function($,jQuery){mw.user.tokens.set({"editToken":"SOME_TOKEN_2","patrolToken":"SOME_TOKEN_3","watchToken":"SOME_TOKEN_4"});},{},{});/* cache key: sitedb-mediawiki_:resourceloader:filter:minify-js:7:SOME_ROKEN */}</script>

<script>if(window.mw){mw.config.set({"wgBackendResponseTime":320});}</script>
```

I installed MediaWiki 1.28 from the official site from the tar archive to a new directory and a new schema, without additional extensions. I set up Gadget-UTCLiveClock, but it still does not work on the article page.

There are no errors in the logs.

What could be the problem?

MediaWiki   1.28.0
PHP     5.6.30-0+deb8u1 (apache2handler)
MySQL   5.5.54-0+deb8u1
Debian  Jessie 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.39-1+deb8u2 (2017-03-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Those screenshots are not useful. You should look for something like `<script>(window.RLQ=window.RLQ||[]).push(function(){mw.loader.load("/w/load.php?debug=false\u0026lang=en\u0026modules=user\u0026skin=vector\u0026user=<username>\u0026version=abcdefg");});</script>` close to the end of the page.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Now I will add the necessary information.

Comment: I added the function code to the start message.

Comment: It's a bit hard to follow which snippet is for which of the three setups. The first one includes the loader call `ext.gadget.UTCLiveClock` so if that does not work you should check what URL is loaded (it will include the same string) and what it returns. If there is an error, the script URL will contain the error message.